# Convert dd-mmm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in sparksql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, date-format, aws-glue

I have a date value in this format '`dd-mmm-yyyy`'(Example31-Mar-2020) in a glue table. I need to transform this to '`yyyy-mm-dd`' (output:2020-03-31) format using sparkSql.

I have tried. "`date_format(reference_line_attribute3, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`" but this just gives null as output.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: `to_date` first.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
df.withColumn("newDate", 
   date_format(
               to_date($"reference_line_attribute3", "dd-MMM-yyyy"),
               "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

**Output**

```
+-------------------------+----------+
|reference_line_attribute3|   newDate|
+-------------------------+----------+
|              31-Mar-2020|2020-03-31|
+-------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you!     date_format(to_date(reference_line_attribute3, "dd-MMM-yyyy"), "yyyy-MM-dd"), did the trick!

Comment: awesome!, please accept the question so if any other have the same issue can find it easily